# Nothig shows in my list

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm build an app for Android and have some difficulties getting data into my listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String logTag = "MFLog";

private Friend friend;
private FriendLogic friendLogic;
ArrayList<Friend> friends;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    friendLogic = new FriendLogic(this);
    //addFriend();
    friends = new ArrayList<>();
    //friendLogic.deleteFriend(1);
    friends = friendLogic.getFriends();

    for (Friend f : friends) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Friend " + f.getFirstName());
    }

    Friend getFriend = friendLogic.getFriend(3);
    Log.d(logTag, "Specific " + getFriend.getFirstName() + " " +      getFriend.getSurName());

    getFriend.setFirstName("Jimmy");
    Friend changedFriend = friendLogic.updateFriend(getFriend);
    Log.d(logTag, "Specific changed " + changedFriend.getFirstName() + " " + changedFriend.getSurName());

    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Friend> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friends_listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void addFriend() {
    friend = new Friend("Jimmy", "Lillegaard", 31223344, 6, "Søparken");
    friendLogic = new FriendLogic(this);
    friendLogic.saveFriend(friend);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend>{



    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.friends_cell, friends);
       }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       View friendsView = convertView;

        if(friendsView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           friendsView = li.inflate(R.layout.friends_cell, parent, false);
        }

        Friend currentFriend = friends.get(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) friendsView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        name.setText(currentFriend.getFirstName() + " " +      currentFriend.getSurName());

        return friendsView;
    }

}
```

For some reason this wont fill up my listview which is located in mainlayout:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    android:id="@+id/friends_listView" />
```

I Inflate it with a custom cell looking like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_width="87dp"
    android:layout_height="98dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<ImageButton
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="113dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="169dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="63dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="0" />

<TextView
    android:text="Jimmy Lillegaard"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75" />
```

When i run the app, the screen is blank. What did i miss?

I have addede some more logs and changed the code a bit

public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList friends) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, friends);
           this.friends = friends;

```
        for (Friend f : friends) {
            Log.d(logTag, "Friends inside adapter " + f.getFirstName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       View friendsView = convertView;

        if(friendsView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           friendsView = li.inflate(R.layout.friends_cell, parent, false);
        }

        Friend currentFriend = friends.get(position);

        Log.d(logTag, "Friend inside the getView @Override" + currentFriend.getFirstName());


        TextView name = (TextView) friendsView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        name.setText(currentFriend.getFirstName() + " " + currentFriend.getSurName());

        Log.d(logTag, "The text on the textViev name " + name.getText().toString());
```

Here are my logs:

06-16 08:32:30.517 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: Friend Hans
06-16 08:32:30.517 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: Friend Jimmy
06-16 08:32:30.517 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: Specific Jimmy Lillegaard
06-16 08:32:30.547 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: Specific changed Jimmy Lillegaard
06-16 08:32:30.547 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: Friends inside adapter Hans
06-16 08:32:30.556 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: Friends inside adapter Jimmy
06-16 08:32:30.597 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: Friend inside the getView @Override Hans
06-16 08:32:30.597 2608-2608/com.app.friends.myfriends D/MFLog: The text on the textViev name Hans Lillegaard

Comment: are you getting all log value print you are logging ?

Comment: where you are adding items to your list ? because i could not find it here that is why your list shows empty

Comment: Yes i have the data in my sqllite and in the constructer of the the adapter i add the list like this "super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.friends_cell, friends);"
and set the text field like this 
"TextView name = (TextView) friendsView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        name.setText(currentFriend.getFirstName() + " " +      currentFriend.getSurName());"

Comment: Run in debug mode, try and see what happens where in the code.

Comment: I've added more logs now, when running in debug i cant find the missing thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Well after working on this for days, i just found out that apparently i can not use a constraint layout inside another constraint layout.

I solved this by changing the cell layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/friend_image"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="The Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/friend_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_image"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/friend_image" />

  <ImageButton
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp" />

  <ImageButton
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameText" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```